# How to read all images in a folder and convert it into numbers in Python 3?

Tags: python, image

I'm making a Facial recognition app. I have a folder include 400 images of people and I want to load it into a variable so that I can reduce it dimension using PCA in sckitlearn. How can I do it?

```
I'm using Python 3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be helpful if you can share what have you tried so far and where have you stuck? Your current question is too broad to answer.

Comment: Please post the code you've written. Thanks.